# How does the pipe (|) operator work in Android while setting some properties?

Tags: java, android, operators

My question may be basic, but I am wondering how the pipe operator works in the following contexts in Android :

We can set multiple input types in layout:

```
android:inputType = "textAutoCorrect|textAutoComplete"
```

We can set multiple flags to an intent as follows:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Also we can set some properties as follows:

```
tvHide.setPaintFlags(tvHide.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```

There are multiple instances where we can see such examples in Android.

So my question is, does the `|` operator act like the bitwise OR operator or does it just concat the results or something else?
If it acts like the bitwise OR operator, then how does it make the expected result correct? Can anybody enlighten me on this?

Comment: yes this is a bitwise OR

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but this resource https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/understanding-bitwise-operators--active-11301 may be of use. It shows you different bitwise operators in "table form" so you can see what exactly happens and what the result is.

Comment: Java does not have a pipe operator.

Comment: curious how you got so many upvotes in such a short amount of time for a question to which the answer can be found by googling the title

Comment: @TimCastelijns Probably because it is a well-asked and interesting question, if not entirely well-researched.

Comment: @MichaelDodd considering it was asked at least twice before, it is not that interesting, not to mention the existing questions popped up on the screen while OP was asking this one

Comment: @TimCastelijns By "interesting" I mean relative to most other questions that pop up in the [android] New Questions queue on a daily basis ;)

Comment: `curious how you got so many upvotes in such a short amount of time for a question`. Indeed. Very special. There should be more questions here like that that ask for the obvious to a lot. ;-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is a `bitwise inclusive OR` operation, primarily used for setting flags ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)). Consider the following flags:

```
byte flagA = 0b00000001;
byte flagB = 0b00000100;
```

If we use the `|` operator, these two flags are combined:

```
byte flags = flagA | flagB; // = 0b00000101
```

Which allows us to set properties or other small bits of status information in a small amount of memory (typically an Integer with most Android flags).

Note that a flag should only ever have one bit "active", i.e. have a value equal to 2^n. This is how we know what flags have been set when we go to check the combined flag holder variable using a `bitwise AND` operator, e.g.

```
if ((flags & flagA) == flagA) {
    // Flag A has been set
    ...
}
```

Comment: The only thing to add is that for this mechanism to work the flags have to be powers of two so the bits don't overlap.

Comment: @Juan Good catch, was hoping that would be implicit from the way I wrote that answer out, but yes, each flag should have only have one bit "active" i.e. be 2^n

Comment: Yeah,, that the thing,, means How setFlag() know how to use combined results

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki Good to hear that it's helped. If I've answered your question sufficiently, please accept this answer by clicking the ✔ icon on the left.

Comment: `How setFlag() know how to use combined results ` setFlags() knows nothing about flags or of combining flags. The compiler adds the flags and then setFlags() gets a byte. Maybe an nteger.

Comment: @greenapps Indeed, the function `setFlags()` in `Intent` just assigns the value to a variable called `mFlags` and returns the `Intent` instance.

Comment: It can also be applied to `int`, so it's not always for `byte`.  for example `final int flag = PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE`

Answer (score 1):

The pipe in java is the bitwise OR.
When using it in some Android properties, it conceptually does the same thing.
This is that the options separated by the pipe are added.